# Get rid of a warning?

Tags: java

How can I get rid of the warning in the following code without using `@SuppressWarnings`?

```
// consoles is an ArrayList of console. The class console extends the class item.
// pcs is an ArrayList of pc. The class pc extends the class item.
public static boolean verify(String type, String model)
{
    ArrayList<item> obj;
    if(type == null) return false;
    else if(type.equals("console")) obj = (ArrayList<item>) consoles.clone();
    else if(type.equals("pc")) obj = (ArrayList<item>) pcs.clone();
    else return false;

    for(int j = 0; j < obj.size(); j++)
        if(obj.get(j).get_model().equals(model))
            return true;

    return false;
}
```

I am getting the warning `unchecked` in the lines: `else if(type.equals`

Comment: 'unchecked' is the warning

Comment: You're getting that warning because the `clone()` method returns `Object`, and it's not guaranteed to be `ArrayList<item>`.

Comment: @ saiarcot895: I see, thanks for pointing this out... Is there an easy way to avoid getting it?

Comment: without the @SuppressWarning you can't.

Comment: Maybe you can instruct your choice IDE about the severity threshold of the warnings it should show.  Eclipse has a lot of options for that under Window->Preferences->Java->Compiler->Errors/Warnings.  However, the only real way to do that is to use a `@SuppressWarnings`annotation

Comment: @Jorge_B Your answer was not wrong, I just wanted you to address why it is required and why there is no other direct solution.

Comment: Actually it was wrong, I had failed to answer to the point to the question, that is why I deleted it.  saiarcot895 has a quite relevant answer, not only about the warnings, but about the use of `clone()` too by the way

Comment: @Jorge_B: worry not, thanks for answering my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The warning is because the `clone()` method returns an `Object`, and so the compiler isn't sure that the object is an `ArrayList`.

Instead of using `clone()`, I recommend either:

1. using `new ArrayList<>(consoles)` (this is the copy constructor).
2. creating a new `ArrayList<item>` and using the `addAll` method to copy the items over to the new `ArrayList<item>`.

On an unrelated note, while the `ArrayList` does implement `clone()`, note that not all classes may do so, and so `clone()` might not work.

Comment: `using new ArrayList<>(consoles) (this is the copy constructor).` This solved the warning message. Thanks a lot!